# using sqlite3 in multithreading

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, python-multithreading

I am writing a server program for many clients and i used threads.
Every client can make an action that requires writing or reading from sqlite database.
Do I need to open and close connection for every action or to open the database once for all the clients to share one connection?
Example for my code:

```
    if command == "s":
        conn = open_database() #connect to the database
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''SELECT s FROM users WHERE username=?''', (username,))
        s= cursor.fetchone()[0]
        conn.close()
        if not s:
            s= "Empty!"
        clientsock.send(str(s))
```

I also used insert command to the database.

Comment: If it is a server program there should be a job queue in server app to process client requests. There should be one static connection between server app and db. It is not logical to make it multi-threaded in my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One connection has exactly one transaction, so your program is likely to blow up when multiple threads try to share the same connection without locking around all transactions.

Use one connection per thread.

(If you need high concurrency, SQLite [might not be the best choice](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).)